# add a file name to lines in this file

Tags: text-processing, filenames

I have fasta files, coming from different samples eg: 01.fasta, 02.fasta, etc.

All of them contain OTU list with the following pattern:

```
>OTU1
CCTACGGGCGGCTGCAGT

>OTU2
CCTACGGGTGGCTGCAG
```

I would like to add the file's name (eg. 01, 02, etc) to each `>OTU*` line in the fasta file to receive the following: `>OTU1_01`, `>OTU2_01`, etc.

Can you help me write a script that automatically does it for all files in my folder?

Answer (score 3):

**Make sure you have a backup of your files before starting to change them all**

You can run something like the following:

```
for i in *.fasta; do nr="${i%.fasta}"; sed -i 's/^>OTU\(.*\)$/>OTU\1_'$nr'/' "$i"; done
```

if you have a version of `sed` that supports `-i` (in place editing).

The `nr="${i%.fasta}"` part gets you the number from the filename. The `\(.*\)` matches the number after `>OTU`, which then gets reinserted with `\1`

Answer (score 0):

`gawk` 4.1.0 onwards, an in-place editing option is available. So in one fell swoop

```
awk -i inplace -v INPLACE_SUFFIX=.bak '
  BEGINFILE{x=FILENAME; sub(/\..*/, "", x)};
  /^>OT/{$0 =$0"_"x};
  {print}' *.fasta
```

will update files as needed in-place. `-v INPLACE_SUFFIX=.bak` causes original files to be backed up with a `.bak` suffix